# Android: Tabs + Swipe : how to know the previous screen from where the page has navigated?

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

I have a project where I've used Tabs + Swipe UI. The problem here is I want to know from which tab the tab been navigated from. like, for the tab 2, I can navigate from tab 1 as well as tab 3. So I want to know from which tab I have navigated.

Comment: keep local var previoustab on your tabListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Velocity tracker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) to find the velocity of the swipe in X-direction (using `.getXVelocity()`). If the value is a negative one, then it was from **tab 1**. Else,  it was from **tab 3**

Comment: A good example related to this is given [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/VelocitytrackerDemo.htm)